# How to query the result of "random_x"

Tags: solr

Say for example we wanted to know what number is returned when we make use of the random field type in run a query such as:

`/select?q=*:*&sort=random_10 ASC`

I want to see what value `random_10` is. How would one query that (in Solr 6.6.2)?

I keep getting this error:

`undefined field _text_`

I do seem to be able to almost get it working with this query:

`/select?fl=random_5&q=*&sort=random_10 ASC`

However, I just get empty objects back:

[image: empty results]

Comment: As far as I know the RandomSortField does not return an actual value to represent itself. You might see something if you append `debug=all` in the output for the values the query is sorted by. Since the field also can be used as a valuesource, using a function on the field might give you the value back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result can be displayed by using the following in the `fl` portion of the query:

`foo:sum(random_555)`

With a full query being:

`/select?fl=foo:sum(random_555)&q=*:*`

And the result:

[image: Results of random values]